# How can I track performance of facebook mobile app ad campaigns

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

As we know, we can use marketing API of facebook to check our campaigns.
But these statistics are aggregated, can not understand my audiences of ads.

Whether there is API to fix this problem?

I just want to get device level info from every ads.

Like:
Get IDFA (advertising ID in iOS) have been installed Application by clicking My facebook ads.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are asking. Are you looking to get the IDFA, in which case you will need to do that yourself on your mobile app. If you are just trying to get the stats for the ad what have you tried?

Comment: @The1Fitz I want to catch data which users have clicked my facebook ads, the data will be included IDFA, IP, device type, system version etc. Is there having any API to do it?

Comment: there is no API to retrieve user level data from Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

User level data is not accessible due to user's privacy. However, you can get some aggregated numbers with more detail by using Facebook Analytics or the `/app_insights` endpoint. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/app_insights